# Is this a proper format of link element for app-indexing in Android?

Tags: android, html, android-intent, android-app-indexing, google-search-platform

I want to add `link` element to website, but I don't know how to use http scheme,

Is is a proper way?

Page Url: `http://package.myapp.org/id-123.html`

App package: `org.myapp.package`

Scheme: `http`

Path: `id-123.html`

Link element in question:

`<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://org.myapp.package/http/id-123.html" />`

Or do I need to fill in participation link to enable app indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is:

`<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://org.myapp.package/http/my-website.com/id-123.html" />`